# sql matching tables with different records via id

Tags: mysql, sql, join, union

I am trying to match 3 tables each containing different values but with the same id and i want to have a mixed result (final table) as shown in the image. How can i achieve that?

[image]

Comment: That's an odd design I would expect to see a product table and tables1 - 3 containing product id

Comment: Anyway search for conditional aggregation.

Comment: yeah i know, but it's an very bad designed legacy system where some reports need to be created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all products from all table without duplicates and save them to temp table. Then simply `LEFT JOIN` temp table with three tables.

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS all_products;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE all_products
SELECT DISTINCT id, product FROM (
  SELECT id, product FROM table1 UNION
  SELECT id, product FROM table2 UNION
  SELECT id, product FROM table3
) AS t;

ALTER TABLE all_products ADD INDEX id(id);

SELECT 
  t.id, t1.product, 
  t1.`count` AS `count table 1`,
  t2.`count` AS `count table 2`,
  t3.`count` AS `count table 3`
FROM
  all_products AS t
  LEFT JOIN table1 AS t1 ON t1.id=t.id
  LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t2.id=t.id
  LEFT JOIN table3 AS t3 ON t3.id=t.id
;
```

You can also use a single query like that:

```
SELECT
  t.id, t.product, 
  t1.`count` AS `count table 1`,
  t2.`count` AS `count table 2`,
  t3.`count` AS `count table 3`
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT id, product FROM (
    SELECT id, product FROM table1 UNION
    SELECT id, product FROM table2 UNION
    SELECT id, product FROM table3
  ) AS a
) AS t
  LEFT JOIN table1 AS t1 ON t1.id=t.id
  LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t2.id=t.id
  LEFT JOIN table3 AS t3 ON t3.id=t.id
;
```